# GCC compiled Win32 program crashes during system DLL call

Tags: c, winapi, pointers, gcc, dll

I try to call `IcmpSendEcho` loaded from `iphlpapi.dll` **without** using the Microsoft SDK libraries. I use GCC 4.8.1 (win32) on Windows 7 x64. I tried it this way:

1. Create required structs and define constants
2. Obtain pointers to DLL functions
3. Call DLL functions

I put together a small example that demonstrates my problem:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct {
  union {
    struct {
      u_char s_b1,s_b2,s_b3,s_b4;
    } S_un_b;
    struct {
      u_short s_w1,s_w2;
    } S_un_w;
    u_long S_addr;
  } S_un;
} IPAddr;


#define IP_FLAG_REVERSE 0x01
#define IP_FLAG_DF      0x02

typedef struct {
  UCHAR  Ttl;
  UCHAR  Tos;
  UCHAR  Flags;
  UCHAR  OptionsSize;
  PUCHAR OptionsData;
} IP_OPTION_INFORMATION;


typedef struct {
  IPAddr                       Address;
  ULONG                        Status;
  ULONG                        RoundTripTime;
  USHORT                       DataSize;
  USHORT                       Reserved;
  PVOID                        Data;
  IP_OPTION_INFORMATION        Options;
} ICMP_ECHO_REPLY;


typedef HANDLE (*IcmpCreateFile_t)();

typedef BOOL (*IcmpCloseHandle_t)(
    HANDLE IcmpHandle // _In_  HANDLE IcmpHandle
);

typedef DWORD (*IcmpSendEcho_t)(
    HANDLE IcmpHandle,  // _In_      HANDLE IcmpHandle,
    IPAddr dst,         // _In_      IPAddr DestinationAddress,
    void * RequestData, // _In_      LPVOID RequestData,
    WORD RequestSize,   // _In_      WORD RequestSize,
    IP_OPTION_INFORMATION * RequestOptions, // _In_opt_  PIP_OPTION_INFORMATION RequestOptions,
    void * ReplyBuffer, // _Out_     LPVOID ReplyBuffer,
    DWORD ReplySize,    // _In_      DWORD ReplySize,
    DWORD Timeout       // _In_      DWORD Timeout
);


HINSTANCE hIPHLPAPI = NULL;
IcmpCreateFile_t  IcmpCreateFile  = NULL;
IcmpCloseHandle_t IcmpCloseHandle = NULL;
IcmpSendEcho_t    IcmpSendEcho    = NULL;

HANDLE hIcmpFile;

int icmp_init() {
    hIPHLPAPI = LoadLibrary("iphlpapi.dll");
    if(hIPHLPAPI == NULL) return 0;

    IcmpCreateFile = (IcmpCreateFile_t) GetProcAddress(hIPHLPAPI, "IcmpCreateFile");
    if(IcmpCreateFile == NULL) return 0;

    IcmpCloseHandle = (IcmpCloseHandle_t) GetProcAddress(hIPHLPAPI, "IcmpCloseHandle");
    if(IcmpCloseHandle == NULL) return 0;

    IcmpSendEcho = (IcmpSendEcho_t) GetProcAddress(hIPHLPAPI, "IcmpSendEcho");
    if(IcmpSendEcho == NULL) return 0;

    hIcmpFile = IcmpCreateFile();
    if(!hIcmpFile) return 0;

    return 1;
}

int icmp_ping(uint32_t ip) {
    // Echo request data
    int dataSize = 32;
    void * data = malloc(dataSize);

    // Reply buffer
    int replySize = sizeof(ICMP_ECHO_REPLY) + 128;
    void * replyBuffer = malloc(replySize);
    if(replyBuffer == NULL) return 0;

    // Send echo request and wait for reply
    IPAddr dst;
    dst.S_un.S_addr = ip;
    printf("Calling IcmpSendEcho\n");
    DWORD dwRetVal = IcmpSendEcho(hIcmpFile, dst, data, dataSize, NULL, replyBuffer, replySize, 1000);
    if(dwRetVal == 0) return 0;

    ICMP_ECHO_REPLY *echoreply = (ICMP_ECHO_REPLY *) replyBuffer;
    printf("Status = %ld\n", echoreply->Status);

    free(replyBuffer);

    return 0;
}

int icmp_free() {
    FreeLibrary(hIPHLPAPI);
    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if(icmp_init()) {
        int pret = icmp_ping(2915201282 /* google.com */);
        printf("icmp_ping returned %d\n", pret);
        icmp_free();
    }
}
```

I compile this example using `gcc -o icmp_test.exe icmpt_test.c`. It prints "Calling IcmpSendEcho" and crashes (see below).

This is not the "real" code but it fails in the same way. The call to `IcmpCreateFile` succeeds, but calling `IcmpSendEcho` crashes the program and makes Windows display "... has stopped working".

I thought the problem might be related to a wrong pointer but I cannot find the problem.

Comment: Your function pointer types have the wrong calling convention.

Comment: @IInspectable What exactly?

Comment: `IcmpCreateFile_t`, `IcmpCloseHandle_t`, and `IcmpSendEcho_t` explicitly need to declare their calling convention, `WINAPI`. For example: `typedef HANDLE (WINAPI* IcmpCreateFile_t)();` You were lucky that `IcmpCreateFile` didn't crash, mostly because it doesn't have any parameters. `IcmpSendEcho` on the other hand ended your streak.

Comment: @IInspectable Dammit, I did not think about that at all. Thank you! If you write an answer, I'll accept it, of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When dyncamically linking a library using [`GetProcAddress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212.aspx) you need to make sure, that you match both signature and calling convention. While the signature is usually trivially easy to get right, it's easy to forget to account for the [calling convention](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k2b2ssfy.aspx).

System modules in Windows always use [`__stdcall`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxk0tw93.aspx), which is also availble through the `WINAPI` preprocessor macro. To fix your code so that the compiler generates the appropriate instructions for the function calls you need to update the following function pointer types to include the appropriate calling convention:

```
typedef HANDLE (WINAPI* IcmpCreateFile_t)();

typedef BOOL (WINAPI* IcmpCloseHandle_t)(
    HANDLE IcmpHandle // _In_  HANDLE IcmpHandle
);

typedef DWORD (WINAPI* IcmpSendEcho_t)(
    HANDLE IcmpHandle,  // _In_      HANDLE IcmpHandle,
    IPAddr dst,         // _In_      IPAddr DestinationAddress,
    void * RequestData, // _In_      LPVOID RequestData,
    WORD RequestSize,   // _In_      WORD RequestSize,
    IP_OPTION_INFORMATION * RequestOptions, // _In_opt_  PIP_OPTION_INFORMATION
    RequestOptions,
    void * ReplyBuffer, // _Out_     LPVOID ReplyBuffer,
    DWORD ReplySize,    // _In_      DWORD ReplySize,
    DWORD Timeout       // _In_      DWORD Timeout
);
```

Comment: Is there any difference between `typedef HANDLE WINAPI (*IcmpCreateFile_t)();` and `typedef HANDLE (WINAPI* IcmpCreateFile_t)();`?

Comment: Read your question and see difference - stack will be corrupted.

Comment: @IInspectable: 'System modules in Windows always use __stdcall' - this is not true, some functions use __cdecl calling convention.

Comment: @justlerning Calling conventions aren't part of standard C++, so the syntax is compiler specific. Placing the calling convention inside the parentheses compiles on most compilers, where your alternative fails on some (MSC, for example). As pointed out by Xearinox, not **all** functions in Windows use `__stdcall`. Notable exceptions are functions with variable arguments, like [`StringCchPrintf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms647541.aspx). Those have to use `__cdecl`, since only the caller knows the number of parameters that have to removed from the stack during cleanup.

Comment: @justlerning All of the above is relevant to 32-bit code. With 64-bit code, things get considerably easier: There is only one [Calling Convention](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9b372w95.aspx) any more, explained under [Parameter Passing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zthk2dkh.aspx).